# Is there an R function for finding if a .LAZ file is contained in a .SHP polygon

Tags: r, shapefile, lidar, las, lidr

I have a folder in which I have several thousand .LAZ files and I would like to select those that are contained in the .SHP polygon. Can it be programmed in R, e.g. by adding a given name to .LAZ files. Loading so many files into a GIS program is not possible.

I tried this script but it doesn't work. do i need to generate .LAS it increases the data significantly.

```
# Install and load necessary packages
install.packages("lidR")
install.packages("rgdal")
library(lidR)
library(rgdal)

# Read the .shp file with the extent
extent <- readOGR(dsn = "/path/to/folder", layer = "filename")

# Read the .laz files in the folder
folder <- "/path/to/folder"
laz_files <- list.files(folder, pattern = "\\.laz$", full.names = TRUE)

# Iterate through the .laz files and select those that overlap with the extent
for (laz_file in laz_files) {
  points <- readLAS(laz_file)
  if (extent(points) %over% extent) {
    cat("File", laz_file, "overlaps with the extent.\n")
    # Create a new file name with the selected file name appended
    new_name <- sub(".laz", paste0("_selected_", basename(laz_file)), laz_file)
    # Save the file under the new name
    writeLAS(points, new_name)
  } else {
    cat("File", laz_file, "does not overlap with the extent.\n")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that (did not test)

```r
library(lidR)
library(sf)
ctg = readLAScatalog("/path/to/folder")
extent = st_read("/path/to/folder/filname.shp")
ctg2 = catalog_intersect(ctg, extent)
ctg2$filename
```